# Sleep in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, sleep

Assumed that there is no "native" way to achieve this, my solution-like was

```
sleep = function(time) {
        var stop = new Date().getTime();
        while(new Date().getTime() < stop + time) {
            ;
        }
        return new Promise((r,_)=> r())
      }
```

So doing `sleep(1000*3).then(()=>console.log("awake"))` it will sleep 3 seconds and then resolve the `Promise`:

(be aware that it will freeze this page one sec.)

```js
sleep = function(time) {
  var stop = new Date().getTime();
  while (new Date().getTime() < stop + time) {;
  }
  return new Promise((r, _) => r())
}
console.log("sleeping...")
sleep(1000 * 1).then(() => console.log("awake"))
```

Assumed that this will run in the main thread it will freeze the main process so that doing

```
sleep(1000*1).then(()=>console.log("awake")); console.log("Hello")
```

it will result in a output

```
VM2628:1 Hello
VM2628:1 awake
```

at very end of the sleep. Of course doing

```
setTimeout(()=>sleep(1000*3).then(()=>console.log("awake")),1000);console.log("Hello")
VM2815:1 Hello
undefined
VM2815:1 awake
```

will make it async, but it does not address my need (to put to `sleep` my main process).
Any better way?

**[UPDATE]**
Promisified version

```
/**
 * Sleep for time [msec]
 * @param time int milliseconds
 * @return Promise delayed resolve
 * @usage
    sleep(1000*3).then(()=>console.log("awake"))
 */
sleepP: function (time) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    var stop = new Date().getTime();
    while (new Date().getTime() < stop + time) {
      ;
    }
    return resolve(true)
  });
}
```

that can be called like

```
await sleepP( 1000 * 3 );
```

Comment: Why do you want to freeze your JS interpreter for 3 seconds?  Why not just program asynchronously like the language was designed to do and you don't have to freeze anything?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is no need to freeze at all. Because of javascripts asynchronicity we can leave a part of the code for some time and resume later. At first we need a promising timer:

```
 const timer = ms => new Promise( res => setTimeout(res, ms));
```

Then we can simply use it:

```
console.log("wait 3 seconds")
timer(3000).then(_=>console.log("done"));
```

Or with a bit syntactic sugar:

```
(async function(){
  console.log("wait 3 seconds");
  await timer(3000);
  console.log("done");
})()
```

---

If you really want to freeze ( very bad ), you don't need promises at all:

```
function freeze(time) {
    const stop = new Date().getTime() + time;
    while(new Date().getTime() < stop);       
}

console.log("freeze 3s");
freeze(3000);
console.log("done");
```

Answer (score 6):

### Since Node v15.0.0 there is a Promise-based 'sleep' function built into node

You can sleep by using the [Timers Promises API](https://nodejs.org/api/timers.html#timers-promises-api).

```js
import {setTimeout} from 'timers/promises';

await setTimeout(100);
```

If you want to use also use the old callback-based `setTimeout()` - or just like the name `sleep()` - you can alias the promise timer.

```js
import {setTimeout as sleep} from 'timers/promises';

// promise `setTimeout` aliased as `sleep`
await sleep(100);
console.log('I waited'));

// regular callback `setTimeout` (scheduling timers)
setTimeout(() => console.log('I also waited'), 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
function sleep(time, func){
    if (typeof func === 'function'){
        const timer = ms => new Promise( res => setTimeout(res, ms));
        timer(time).then(i=>func());
    }
    else{
        console.log('What about the function bro?')
    }
}
sleep(1000, function(){
    console.log('hello')
    console.log('test')
    var arr = [1,2,3,4]
    arr.forEach(i => console.log(i))
})
```