# How to run a function which call axios for every 30 seconds

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, npm, cheerio

I'm creating a web scraper using node, cheerio and calling the website using axios(async/await). I want the function to run every 30 seconds. I tried using *setTimeout* and *setInterval* but did not get the expected result. Instead got *heap out of memory* error. I want to run the *mvcAppointmentSearch* function in the while loop for every 30 seconds. Following is the code. also attaching the codepen link for better readability.
[Code pen link](https://codepen.io/ghewadesumit/pen/eYRZQzP)

```
const express = require('express');
const request = require('request-promise');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const axios = require('axios');
const cssSelect = require('css-select');
const open = require('open');
// const mvcUrl = 'https://telegov.njportal.com/njmvc/AppointmentWizard/17/';
const mvcUrl = 'https://telegov.njportal.com/njmvc/AppointmentWizard/14/';
const mvcLocation = ['Edison', 'Rahway', 'SouthPlainfield'];
// const mvcLocationNumber = ['240', '252', '239'];
const mvcLocationNumber = ['163'];
const requiredMonths = ['September', 'October'];

const callUrl = async (url, locationNumberIndex) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get(url);
    //console.log('call url', response.data);
    getData(response.data, locationNumberIndex);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
};

const mvcAppointmentSearch = () => {
  for (let i = 0; i < mvcLocationNumber.length; i++) {
    const currentUrl = mvcUrl + mvcLocationNumber[i];
    console.log(mvcLocationNumber[i]);
    callUrl(currentUrl, i);
  }
};

const getData = (html, locationNumberIndex) => {
  let data = [];
  let $ = cheerio.load(html);

  console.log('datais ', $);
  $.prototype.exists = function (selector) {
    return this.find(selector).length > 0;
  };

  const checkerLength = $('div').exists('.alert-danger');

  console.log(checkerLength);
  if (checkerLength) {
    console.log(
      `No appointment available in ${mvcLocation[locationNumberIndex]}`
    );
  } else {
    const dateString = $('.control-label').text();
    const availableMonth = dateString.trim().split(' ')[7];
    const exactDateAvailability = dateString.slice(24, -1);
    console.log(availableMonth);
    if (requiredMonths.includes(availableMonth)) {
      console.log('Hurray there is an appointment available');
      const message = `Appointment available for the location ${mvcLocation[locationNumberIndex]} on ${exactDateAvailability}`;
      open(`${mvcUrl + mvcLocationNumber[locationNumberIndex]}`);
      console.log(message);
    } else {
      console.log('required Month is not available still searching');
    }
  }
};

while (true) {
  try {


    // mvcAppointmentSearch();
// want to run the following function for every 30 seconds.
    mvcAppointmentSearch();
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(`Error has Occured ${err}`);
  }
}
```

Comment: remove `while (true)` loop, then uses `setInterval(mvAppointmentSearch, 30* 1000)`. it sounds like you put `setInterval` into `while(true)` loop, then caused `setInterval` is called again and again until out of memory. actually `setInterval` only needs to be called once, then it will invoke your function future cycles (ex: every 30 seconds).

Comment: or refer to [how to sleep one function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46937581/sleep-in-node-js) to put your function into one `while(true)` loop, then sleep 30 seconds.

Comment: Ohhh yeah. It totally makes sense. Thanks @Sphinx